# How do I preview my mobile web application on a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows, mobile

I am developing a mobile web application that may be browsed in an iPhone. I would like to test this application, but I lack a mobile web device.

How can I test this mobile application on a Windows 7 PC?

Comment: Have you checked the Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange site (currently in beta)? They actually have a question about [tools for testing mobile web apps](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-some-tools-for-testing-mobile-web-apps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is tricky. There aren't any emulators, even the one avaliable on OS X is a bad feel for browsing with a touch screen device. You can at least make sure your site renders using something like browsercam.

The best bet is to get an iOS device. iPod Touches make very good approximate iPhones, especially for web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard this as an answer - I do not see an option for me to comment and I really want to throw in my 1 cent.

Anyway, this is a big issue for me now, too. I am used to developing .NET solutions on my local machine, setting up different sites within IIS 7. I am trying to transition to mobile site development but figuring out how to set up a test environment is becoming a huge obstacle.

I have not yet been able to get an emulator to even browse to any of my localhost sites on my Windows 7 machine. I am wondering if I am going to have to set up a site through my hosting provider for testing purposes only. Obviously this is not an ideal solution, which is why I wanted to chime in on this discussion to see if anyone would be willing to divulge any solutions they have found.